# Как организовать загрузку файлов из сети через WebView, который находится во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-webview

Прошу о помощи, пишу диплом под Android API 26, создал основную деятельность приложения и тут возник вопрос о сохранении файлов с сайта, а именно docx файлов через WebView, который в свою очередь находится во фрагменте. Использовал этот код и он работает, но только в обычной MainActivity, с фрагментом безуспешно.

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG="Diplom";
    private WebView webview;
    public String textOnWebActivity;
    public String filename;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);


        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<String> ArrayStringRasp = new ArrayList<>();



        webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.mwebView);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.permaviat.ru/raspisanie-zamen/");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
            {
                //Checking runtime permission for devices above Marshmallow.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                        downloadDialog(url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);

                    } else {

                        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                        //requesting permissions.
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WebActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Code for devices below API 23 or Marshmallow
                    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                    downloadDialog(url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);

                }
            }
        });



    }
    public void downloadDialog(final String url,final String userAgent,String contentDisposition,String mimetype)
    {
        //getting filename from url.
        filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);
        //alertdialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(WebActivity.this);
        //title of alertdialog
        builder.setTitle("Download");
        //message of alertdialog
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to save " +filename);//Имя файла расаеписания
        //if Yes button clicks.
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                //DownloadManager.Request created with url.
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                //cookie
                String cookie=CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                //Add cookie and User-Agent to request
                request.addRequestHeader("Cookie",cookie);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                //file scanned by MediaScannar
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                //Download is visible and its progress, after completion too.
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                //DownloadManager created
                DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                //Saving files in Download folder
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
                //download enqued
                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                //cancel the dialog if Cancel clicks
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        });
        //alertdialog shows.
        builder.create().show();

    }
```

Прошу помощи и идей как адаптировать данный код для Fragment'a?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код одинаково работает и в фрагменте и в активности(в сам код я не вникал) Опишите, пожалуйста, ошибку и код к ней приводящий.

Пишу в ответы, что бы вставить пример как я добавил Ваш код в фрагмент. downloadDialog переделал в статический метод для простоты.

```
public class WebFragment extends Fragment {


private static final String TAG="Diplom";
private WebView webview;
public String textOnWebActivity;

public WebFragment() {
    //Для фрагментов используется пустой конструктор
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);


    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> ArrayStringRasp = new ArrayList<>();



    webview=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.mwebView);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.permaviat.ru/raspisanie-zamen/");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            //Checking runtime permission for devices above Marshmallow.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && getActivity()!=null) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                    downloadDialog(getActivity(), url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);

                } else {

                    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                    //requesting permissions.
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

                }
            }
            else {
                //Code for devices below API 23 or Marshmallow
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                downloadDialog(getContext(), url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);

            }
        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

public static void downloadDialog(Context context, final String url, final String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype)
{
    //getting filename from url.
    String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);
    //alertdialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    //title of alertdialog
    builder.setTitle("Download");
    //message of alertdialog
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to save " +filename);//Имя файла расаеписания
    //if Yes button clicks.
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //DownloadManager.Request created with url.
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            //cookie
            String cookie= CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            //Add cookie and User-Agent to request
            request.addRequestHeader("Cookie",cookie);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
            //file scanned by MediaScannar
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            //Download is visible and its progress, after completion too.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            //DownloadManager created
            DownloadManager downloadManager=(DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            //Saving files in Download folder
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            //download enqued
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            //cancel the dialog if Cancel clicks
            dialog.cancel();
        }

    });
    //alertdialog shows.
    builder.create().show();

}
```

}

Сам фрагмент встроен в MainActivity таким образом

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/activity_main__web_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="ru.boringbar.foranswers.WebFragment"/>
```